# How to download roboearth from roboearth.rosinstall?

Tags: roboearth, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My roboearth.rosinstall:

```
  - svn:
      uri: https://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/roboearth/repos/public/tags/latest
      local-name: roboearth
  - git:
      uri: http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/git/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_vision.git
      local-name: ccny_vision
      version: master
  - svn:
      uri: https://tum-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge
      local-name: knowledge
  - svn: 
      local-name: knowrob
      uri: http://code.in.tum.de/pubsvn/knowrob/tags/latest
```

When I run:

```
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/cram$ rosinstall . /opt/ros/fuerte roboearth.rosinstall 
  rosinstall operating on /home/sam/code/ros/cram from specifications in rosinstall files  /opt/ros/fuerte, roboearth.rosinstall
  (Over-)Writing /home/sam/code/ros/cram/.rosinstall
  [roboearth] Installing https://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/roboearth/repos/public/tags/latest (version None) to /home/sam/code/ros/cram/roboearth
  WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'svn co  "https://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/roboearth/repos/public/tags/latest" /home/sam/code/ros/cram/roboearth'
   errcode: 1:
  svn: OPTIONS of 'https://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/roboearth/repos/public/tags/latest': SSL handshake failed: Secure connection truncated (https://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de)
  [/vcstools]
  [ccny_vision] Installing http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/git/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_vision.git (version master) to /home/sam/code/ros/cram/ccny_vision
  WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'git clone --recursive http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/git/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_vision.git /home/sam/code/ros/cram/ccny_vision'
   errcode: 128:
  error: Empty reply from server (curl_result = 52, http_code = 0, sha1 = af9ec8a5844e5d9e7a2a6cbb1581cc561012ed2d)
  error: Unable to find af9ec8a5844e5d9e7a2a6cbb1581cc561012ed2d under http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/git/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_vision.git
  Cannot obtain needed tree af9ec8a5844e5d9e7a2a6cbb1581cc561012ed2d
  while processing commit 875a6880ed75bb76a3dfb903180dbcbe7a068233.
  error: Fetch failed.
  [/vcstools]
  [knowledge] Installing https://tum-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge (version None) to /home/sam/code/ros/cram/knowledge
  WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'svn co  "https://tum-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge" /home/sam/code/ros/cram/knowledge'
   errcode: 1:
  svn: OPTIONS of 'https://tum-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge': SSL handshake failed: Secure connection truncated (https://tum-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net)
  [/vcstools]
  [knowrob] Installing http://code.in.tum.de/pubsvn/knowrob/tags/latest (version None) to /home/sam/code/ros/cram/knowrob
  [knowrob] Done.
  Exception caught during install: Error processing 'roboearth' : [roboearth] Checkout of https://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/roboearth/repos/public/tags/latest version None into /home/sam/code/ros/cram/roboearth failed.
  Error processing 'ccny_vision' : [ccny_vision] Checkout of http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/git/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_vision.git version master into /home/sam/code/ros/cram/ccny_vision failed.
  Error processing 'knowledge' : [knowledge] Checkout of https://tum-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge version None into /home/sam/code/ros/cram/knowledge failed.
  
  ERROR in config: Error processing 'roboearth' : [roboearth] Checkout of https://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/roboearth/repos/public/tags/latest version None into /home/sam/code/ros/cram/roboearth failed.
  Error processing 'ccny_vision' : [ccny_vision] Checkout of http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/git/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_vision.git version master into /home/sam/code/ros/cram/ccny_vision failed.
  Error processing 'knowledge' : [knowledge] Checkout of https://tum-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge version None into /home/sam/code/ros/cram/knowledge failed.
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/cram$
```

It seems only knowrob download successfully.

What's happened?

How to fix it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50052/how-to-download-roboearth-from-roboearth.rosinstall?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As your error messages indicate, there is an SSL problem with SVN. I guess this is due to the self-assigned SSL certificate of the RoboEarth server. http://ros.org/wiki/roboearth gives some hints on how this may be solved (Section 2.1 callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt required error message).

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HiroCollins](https://answers.ros.org/users/6334/hirocollins/) on 2013-09-02**:
I am having the same problem. I entered the command to accept the self-assigned certificate and it does not solve my problem. I am using ros groovy, I replaced /opt/ros/fuerte with /opt/ros/groovy/ . Sam, how did you solve your problem? Is Roboearth working with groovy yet?

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2013-09-02**:
This problem is independent of RoboEarth and even of ROS, it's just an SVN problem. Try to call the command manually from the command line and follow the instructions at the given link to fix the issues. 'svn co  "https://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/roboearth/repos/public/tags/latest" /home/sam/code/ros/cram/roboearth'